# On the Least Quadratic Non-residue and Integer Factoring

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

A result by Chowla/Fridlender/Salié says that (with a
constant $c \gt 0$) there are infinitely many primes such that
all integers $a$ with $1 \le a \le c \cdot \log(p)$ are quadratic residues
mod $p$.

If $N$ is an odd composite integer of unknown factorization, we can look for a difference of squares representation of $N$ as

$$N = x^2 - y^2, x,y \in \mathbb{Z}. \tag 1$$

Let $p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k$ be a prime basis where

$$M = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i \gt N \tag 2$$

and let

$$N \equiv N_i \equiv x_i^2 - y_i^2 \pmod {p_i}. \tag 3$$

Let $n_p$ denote the least quadratic non-residue modulo $p$.

**Question: Is it possible to select $p_i$ such that $x_i^2 \bmod p_i, y_i^2 \bmod p_i \lt n_{p_i}$?**

**Context:** If we are able to select $p_i$ such that $x_i^2 \bmod p_i,y_i^2 \bmod p_i \lt n_{p_i}$ then we can find $x_i^2, y_i^2$ modulo $M$ by applying Chinese Remainder Theorem in time

$$
\begin{align}
O(c_1 \log p_1 & \cdot c_2 \log p_2 \cdots c_{k-1} \log p_{k-1} \cdot c_k \log p_k) \\
& \approx O(C \log p_k \cdot \log p_k \cdots \log p_k) \\
& \approx O(C (\log p_k)^k)  \\
\end{align} \tag 4
$$

The implication of an affirmative answer means there is a polylogarithmic time algorithm for integer factoring.

**Claim:** We can effectively select $\{p_i\}$ such that $M \gt N \land x_i^2 \bmod p_i, y_i^2 \bmod p_i \lt n_{p_i}$.

**Can we prove or disprove this claim?**

**Note:** Some empirical testing shows that the primes in the basis have to be $\ge 5$. This was established by running brute force Chinese Remaindering and determining that for some $M_i =  \prod_{j = 1}^i p_j$ the set of Chinese Remainder solutions is empty. This condition does not arise when the smallest prime in the basis is $5$.